# Neo4j how to handle special characters like ” \ in Cypher statements

Tags: neo4j, cypher, py2neo

I am using py2neo to load JSON data into Neo4j as chyper statements. 
My problem is that sometimes there are signs as `“ ‘  \` etc in the strings I want to import as properties to Nodes:

`MERGE (p:Node {name:’This  sign ‘ gives  error’})`

If I change to:

`MERGE (p:Node {name:” This  sign ‘ gives  error”})`

It will work for the statement over but it will fail when a `“` is in an input string.

Is there a way to say that all (or almost all) special character is allowed inside the string?
Sorry if this is a stupid question :)

Answer (score 10):

I would suggest to use parameters, then the cypher parser doesn't see them.

And it's just an name -> string you pass via a dictionary to the execute method.

Comment: I can't find it. Can you put a link please?

Comment: https://neo4j.com/docs/python-manual/current/session-api/#python-driver-transaction-configuration

Answer (score 9):

If you want to include double quotes, you can wrap in single quotes:

```
CREATE (n:Node {name:'hello " world'}) 
RETURN n.name

n.name
hello " world
```

If you want to include single quotes, you can wrap in double quotes:

```
CREATE (n:Node {name:"hello ' world"}) 
RETURN n.name

n.name
hello ' world
```

If it's more complicated than that, you can escape the character:

```
CREATE (n:Node {name:"hello \" world"}) 
RETURN n.name

n.name
hello " world
```

You can also include backslashes by escaping them:

```
CREATE (n:Node {name:"hello \\ world"}) 
RETURN n.name

n.name
hello \ world
```

Comment: Also, don't forget triple-single quotes `'''a 'quoted' word'''`and triple-double quotes `"""another "quoted" word"""`.

Comment: @NigelSmall How do you get triple quotes to work? I am getting a `Neo.ClientError.Statement.InvalidSyntax` error when I try to execute something like `MATCH (n:Test {id:'test'}) SET n.label = '''John Doe's house''';`