# Neo4J transactional REST api string escape doesn't work

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

While sending off Cypher queries to [Neo4J's transactional Cypher API](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-transactional.html), I am running into the following error:

> Neo.ClientError.Request.InvalidFormat Unable to deserialize request:
>   Unrecognized character escape ''' (code 39)

My Cypher query looks like this

```
MATCH (n:Test {id:'test'}) SET n.`label` = 'John Doe\'s house';
```

While this query works just fine when executed in Neo4J's browser interface it fails when using the REST API. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? In case this is not a bug, how do I have to escape `'` to get it working in both?

**Edit:**
I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30514046/981933) and tested the triple single and triple double quotes but they just caused another `Neo.ClientError.Request.InvalidFormat` error to be thrown.

Note: I am using Neo4J 2.2.2

Note 2: Just in case it's important, below is the JSON body I am sending to the endpoint.

```
{"statements":[
  {"statement": "MATCH (n:Test {id:'test'}) SET n.`label` = 'John Doe\'s house';"}
]}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to escape the \ too:

```
{"statements":[
  {"statement": "MATCH (n:Test {id:'test'}) SET n.`label` = 'John Doe\\'s house';"}
]}
```

But if you use parameters (recommended), you can do

```
{"statements":[
  {"statement": "MATCH (n:Test {id:'test'}) SET n.`label` = {lbl}",
   "parameters" : {"lbl" : "Jane Doe's house"}
  }

]}
```

Comment: Thanks! Should have figured out it's because of JSON. :)