# neo4j throws error for "\" character

Tags: csv, neo4j

I am exporting csv file and need to read line one by one.

One of the line in csv file contains the string `"C:\Program Files\"`. Because of this line it throws the below error.

> At D:\workdir\Neo4j_Database\Database1\import\Data.csv:22798 - there's
>   a field starting with a quote and whereas it ends that quote there
>   seems to be characters in that field after that ending quote. That
>   isn't supported. This is what I read: 'CMM 10.0.1 Silent Installation
>   will install SW always in "C:\Program Files"",V10.0,
>   ,,,,,,,,105111,AVASAAIS AG,E,,"G,"'

If I remove the last \ of the line then it does not throw this error.

I am not sure how to resolve this without modifying the csv file.

Note: CSV loader used LOAD CSV.

Comment: Could it be causing the last double quote to be treated as an escaped double quote?  In which case, you'd need to add an additional quote character.  Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30513601/neo4j-how-to-handle-special-characters-like-in-cypher-statements

Comment: Which CSV loader are you using? neo4j-admin, neo4j-import, LOAD CSV, ...?

Comment: If you are using neo4j to import, check out the documentation https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/

Comment: @GaborSzarnyas LOAD CSV is used

Comment: @roelofs This will help but if we can do something from neo4j side it will better. Changing the csv file is not good option in my case.